# GMC Sierra SLT 2018 Stuck Tailgate

Tags: tailgate

I installed a tonneau cover on my truck and put the ~6’ cardboard box for the tonneau cover into the bed of the truck. With the tonneau closed, covering the entire bed, I shut the tailgate. The cardboard box was a little longer than the bed, so I forcefully shut the tailgate. It locked but now I can’t get the tailgate open, and with the tonneau cover on, I can’t reach into the bed of the truck to, for example, pull out the cardboard box. Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Push hard on the tailgate then try the lock again.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Do you want to add that as an answer and I can mark it as such? Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option that you can tey is to push hard on the tailgate and cycle the lock again.
This is because the box is loading the catches and preventing them from releasing.